# My springboot application creates a pdf file on openshift how do I get url for that file

Tags: java, file, openshift, spring-boot

My springboot application generates a pdf file on openshift. How do I get correct URL for that file?
I use below code to create pdf file:

```
        Blob blob = document.getScanned();
        fileName = document.getFileName() ;
        InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
        int fileLength = in.available();

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        byte[] buff = blob.getBytes(1,fileLength);
        out.write(buff);
        out.close()
```

I am able to access pdf file on local tomcat server http://localhost:8080/filename, but for openshift server when try to access the file with http://DonmainName/filename I am not getting the pdf file.

Please advice. Thank you

Comment: How do you know if you can write to "filePath"?

Comment: What does it say in your log files?  Can you verify the file is being created there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openshift does not support url's for files created in application to used openly.

I am using amazon s3 for documents.